# How to plot this data into GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot, p2p, topology

I have a program producing data like this:

```
0.5 0.5
0.49597550441921423 0.7868142593062702

0.5 0.5
0.6538646510750382 0.5364703734652149
```

an so on..

This is network topology data. I am told this is gnuplot friendly data however
I ask how to plot this data to gnuplot as it's is not a program I am 
familiar with. Ideally the data should form star pattern clusters. Should also add
this data is in a .dat file however I worked it to a .txt for readability.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of plot do you want to make?  Do you want points?  lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple:

```
plot 'yourdatafile' using 1:2
```

should plot *something*.  However, actually customizing the plot to look exactly how you want it is the tricky part.

Comment: Thank you it works great. Luckily the clustering is simply a line plot.